# Динамичный расчет в calc()

Tags: css

#### Описание

Для адаптивности который автоматически подстроит страницу под любые размеры устройства создаю переменную `--size-standart` в css:

```css
:root {
    --size-standart: calc(410px / 1vmin);
}
```

... где `410px` по моим расчетам просто подходящий размер.
Теперь если задать размеры элементов с помощью `--size-standart`:

```html
<button style="padding: calc(var(--size-standart) / 4)">
  <img style="height: var(--size-standart); aspect-ratio: 1;">
</button>
```

... то они должны подгоняться под размер экрана независимо от типа устройства.

---

Проблема в том, что `calc()` не считает `410px / 1vmin`, потому что "[делитель должен быть `<number>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc#%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81)".

#### Вопрос

По идеи `1vmin` это число в пикселях (к примеру у меня 7.456px), а делить пиксели не должно быть проблем. **Так все таки как можно в css считать  `410px / 1vmin` хоть с `calc()`, хоть без него?**

Comment: может лучше по старинке, резиновый макет на `display: grid`?  https://habr.com/ru/companies/edison/articles/344878/

Comment: @puffleeck так `grid` не может адаптировать под разные размеры экранов. К тому же я не совсем помню зачем задал этот вопрос 8 месяцев назад.))

Comment: как раз наоборот, вся суть той статьи - объяснение как адаптировать и макет и контент под любой экран одновременно. в этом и фишка "резиновой" верстки) `~не помню что хотел 8 месяцев назад` эт еще фигня, рядом еще пачка вопросов всплыла с в плоть до десятилетней давности...) вот поэтому... хотелось бы передать привет тем кто поднял и этот пост и те редактированием)))

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен, что это можно реализовать средствами css, но всегда можно просчитать это через js:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const img = document.querySelector('img');

const baseSize = 410;

const resizeElems = function() {

  let width = window.innerWidth / 100;                      // 1vw
  let height = window.innerHeight / 100;                    // 1vh

  let min = Math.min(width, height);                        // 1vmin

  let res = baseSize / min;                                 // ваш --size-standart
  btn.style.padding = (res / 4) + "px";                     // паддинг кнопки
  img.style.height = res + "px";                            // высота картинки
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resizeElems); // просчет при загрузке страницы
window.onresize = resizeElems;                              // просчет при изменении размера окна
```

```html
<button>
  <img src="https://site.ru/image.png">
</button>
```

Comment: За ответ спасибо, но как вы могли заметить, как в вопросе так и в тегах нету javascript, так как я ищу решение для css.